# Strange issues when using boolean to create indentation of pattern

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

I've been trying to create a pattern indentation into a mesh surface using Boolean, and been facing some strange issues which I'd greatly appreciate any help on.

To start off, this is the pattern which was originally a SVG which I shrinkwrapped onto the surface and "thickened" using Geometry Nodes:

[image: Pattern on top of mesh]

This is the desired result I would like to achieve using Boolean - this works before I click "apply":

[image: Desired Result!]

However, when I click apply result, I see the following:

[image: applied result 1]
[image: applied result 2]

The above deviates from what I want - where parts of the pattern is not "imprinting" on the mesh surface. Do you know what may be happening?

I've also attached the Blend file here: [image]

TIA!

Comment: Hi. I don't know if it's what you want, but apply the modifiers for the Pattern shrinkwrap object, then apply the modifier for the cube.

Answer (score 0):

1. apply scale + rotation for your pattern object
2. apply shrinkwrap
3. apply GN

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$\hspace{15pt}$My guess is that your objects are in cyclic dependency. The pattern's Shrinkwrap modifier depends on the 'Cube' geometry, but the 'Cube' geometry is modified by the Boolean modifier which depends on the pattern object.

The solution is simple:

$\hspace{15pt}$Disable the Boolean modifier, apply the Shrinkwrap, and then re-enable the Boolean modifier.

Or, if you need to keep the Shrinkwrap:

$\hspace{15pt}$Duplicate the 'cube', using one with no Boolean modifier and hidden as the Shrinkwrap target, while the other continues with the Boolean modifier.

[image]

[image]